# Importing Bootstrap 4 JS into project

Tags: wordpress, webpack, bootstrap-4

I'm attempting to import Bootstraps js into my projects main entry point but I'm having some difficulty. I'm sure I have all the required dependencies (jquery and popper.js) and it looks like the js is being imported when I check my bundled file, but Bootstrap Collapse for example isn't working.

Here are my apps dependencies in package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "headroom.js": "^0.12.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "webpack": "^5.58.2"
}
```

And here are the imports from my apps main entry point

```
import $ from "jquery";
import "popper.js";
import 'bootstrap';
```

Can anyone see where I might be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you're using Bootstrap 5 but are you calling it via this bundle?

```
cdn.jsdelivr.net/.../bootstrap.bundle.min.js
```

I ask because, if so, Popper is included in that bundle and does not need to be called separately. I cannot remember if Popper effects the Collapse function or not, it might do since elements are shown and hidden.... And the only possible thing I can see at the moment is that Popper may be getting called twice and screwing things up.